# Importing ASIHTTP , Objective-c?

Tags: objective-c

When trying to use ASIHTTP.

```
ASIHTTP: ld: duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_ASIAuthenticationDialog.request in
```

I keep getting this error

[image]

I did tried
 `Product -> Clean Target / etc`, no luck.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you import the .h file instead of the .m

```
#import @"ASIAuthenticationDialog.h"
```

Instead of

```
#import @"ASIAuthenticationDialog.m"
```

Importing the .m file will produce this linker error.

Comment: nope, that's not it...even if I do not import anything it gives that error. All I did was add the "Classes" folder from AIS into the project

Answer (score 0):

I can Import just fine, but when I build I get a ton of errors referring to ARC (Automatic reference counting). I guess it hasn't been converted yet. Anyone know if it is being optimized to run with ARC?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with this issue after linking a static library that already included the ASIHTTPRequest project. To fix it I had to remove the linker flags "-all_load -ObjC" from my app project.

Unfortunately this leads to other issues, like Categories not working in the static library I was linking.